# How to show user's joined group from Facebook?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my web project, user will login using Facebook, Using my FB app I want to access users joined groups list. I want to show that list to the user. User will select the desired group from that list and submit it back in the website.

Accessing user group will require a facebook permission and review. I submit my app and I got this response- user_groups

General
The user_groups permission is only approved for apps that let people use Facebook on platforms or devices that don’t have a Facebook app. If you're building an app on Android, iOS, Web or Desktop, for example, you won't be approved for this permission.
 I am not able to understand the meaning of it. Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: It means that FB won't allow you to use the permission, because there's a native client for the Android platform already.